# prevent override my intent by incoming Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

on my receiver, I receive Intents, the BroadCast send intent every second... I want to prevent the incoming Intent from overriding the current one until I get the information from the current intent.

**My attempt:**

```
readytoReceive=true;
```

.
.

```
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
if (readytoReceive){
    readytoReceive=false; // stop incoming Intent
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) { // get info.
                {
                    SendRandom.incom.setFrom(bundle.get("From").toString());
                    SendRandom.incom.setTo(bundle.get("To").toString());
                    SendRandom.incom.setTogender(bundle.get("toGender").toString());
                    SendRandom.incom.my_gender = bundle.get("SenderGender").toString();
                    SendRandom.incom.type = bundle.getInt("msgType");
                    SendRandom.incom.url = bundle.get("url").toString();
                    SendRandom.incom.userID = bundle.get("SenderID").toString();
                    SendRandom.incom.setTime(bundle.getString("Time"));
                    SendRandom.incom.setBody(bundle.get("body").toString());
                    Log.d("SOMAA", "Receiver Received: " + SendRandom.incom.getBody() + " type: " + SendRandom.incom.type);
                    MessagesHandler(SendRandom.incom, SendRandom.incom.type);
                    readytoReceive=true; // now let the new intent to come
                }
            } 
        }
        }
    };
```

No compiling  errors nor runtime , but this way prevent the Intents to arrive only the first intent...

**update**

```
  t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                try {
                    if ((incom = (Message) SendRandom.ObjectInServercht.readUnshared()) != null) {
                        Log.e("ESMOA", "Recived :  incomming messages!!!" + incom.getBody());
                        Intent messagesI = new Intent("Messages");
                        messagesI.putExtra("body", incom.getBody());
                        messagesI.putExtra("From", incom.getFrom());
                        messagesI.putExtra("To", incom.getTo());
                        messagesI.putExtra("toGender", incom.getTogender());
                        messagesI.putExtra("SenderGender", incom.my_gender);
                        messagesI.putExtra("msgType", incom.type);
                        messagesI.putExtra("url", incom.url);
                        messagesI.putExtra("SenderID", incom.userID);
                        messagesI.putExtra("Time", incom.getTime());
                        messagesI.putExtra("TEXT", "TEXT");
                        messagesI.setAction("com.esmaeel.incomIM");
                        if(incom.type==MessageType.TextMessage)
                        pushNotification(incom);
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(seekNet.this).sendBroadcastSync(messagesI);
                        Log.d("SOMAA", "sendBroadcast!! " + incom.type + " " + incom.getBody());
                    }


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("SOMAA", "No brodcast!! " + e.getMessage());

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.d("SOMAA", "No brodcast!! " + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch(NullPointerException nu){
                    Log.d("SOMAA","incom is null!!");
                }
            }
        }, 0, 10); << I need faster broadcasting so changed from 1000 (1 sec) to 10, (1/100 sec)
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that readyToReceive=true; is never hit.  Step through with the debugger and see what happens.  Is this surrounded with a try-catch?

Comment: You say the broadcasts are sent every second. If that's the case then it worries me that you think you need to block subsequent broadcasts while you process the current one. If it's taking longer than 1 second for `onReceive(...)` to complete then you're doing something wrong. The `onReceive(...)` method should do as little work as possible - even a few hundred milliseconds might be considered to be a long time for it to complete.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (readytoReceive){
readytoReceive=false; // stop incoming Intent
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) { // get info.
            {
                SendRandom.incom.setFrom(bundle.get("From").toString());
                SendRandom.incom.setTo(bundle.get("To").toString());
                SendRandom.incom.setTogender(bundle.get("toGender").toString());
                SendRandom.incom.my_gender = bundle.get("SenderGender").toString();
                SendRandom.incom.type = bundle.getInt("msgType");
                SendRandom.incom.url = bundle.get("url").toString();
                SendRandom.incom.userID = bundle.get("SenderID").toString();
                SendRandom.incom.setTime(bundle.getString("Time"));
                SendRandom.incom.setBody(bundle.get("body").toString());
                Log.d("SOMAA", "Receiver Received: " + SendRandom.incom.getBody() + " type: " + SendRandom.incom.type);
                MessagesHandler(SendRandom.incom, SendRandom.incom.type);

            }
        } 
      readytoReceive=true; // now let the new intent to come
    }
```

**update**

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(seekNet.this).sendBroadcastSync(messagesI);
```

replace this with

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcastSync(messagesI);
```

Comment: the same :( after several messages it stop receive!